# Show several div on hover

Tags: html, css

I have 4 divs and 4 images and each of them has an ID. I need to show another div when you hover the first div's image.

I wrote this code but only the first image with ID="insta2" and div ID="iinsta2" worked.

```
<style type="text/css">

  #insta1{display:none}
  #insta2{display:none}
  #insta3{display:none}
  #insta4{display:none}

  #iinsta1:hover + #insta1 {
    display: block;
  }
  #iinsta2:hover + #insta2 {
    display: block;
  }
  #iinsta3:hover + #insta3 {
    display: block;
  }
  #iinsta4:hover + #insta4 {
    display: block;
  }
</style>
```

And body:

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="3" rowspan="2" style="text-align:center; width:30%">
    <div id="insta1"><p> Hover 1 </p></div>
    <img id="iinsta2" src="url" style="width:100% ; height:auto">
    <div id="insta2"> <p> Hover </p></div>
  </td>
  <td colspan="4" style="text-align:center; width:40%">
    <img id="iinsta1" src="url" style="width:100% ; height:auto">
  </td>
  <td colspan="3" rowspan="2" style="text-align:center; width:30%">
    <div id="insta3"><p> Hover 3 </p></div>
    <img id="iinsta3" src="url" style="width:100% ; height:auto">
    <div id="insta4"> <p> Hover 4 </p> </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="4" style="text-align:center; width:40%">
    <img id="iinsta4" src="url" style="width:100% ; height:auto">
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this way:

```css
#insta1,
#insta2,
#insta3,
#insta4 {
  display: none;
}
#iinsta1:hover + #insta1,
#iinsta2:hover + #insta2,
#iinsta3:hover + #insta3,
#iinsta4:hover + #insta4 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" rowspan="2" style="text-align:center; width:30%">
      <div id="insta1">
        <p>Hover 1</p>
      </div>
      <img id="iinsta2" src="url" style="width:100% ; height:auto">
      <div id="insta2">
        <p>Hover</p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td colspan="4" style="text-align:center; width:40%">
      <img id="iinsta1" src="url" style="width:100% ; height:auto">
    </td>
    <td colspan="3" rowspan="2" style="text-align:center; width:30%">
      <img id="iinsta3" src="url" style="width:100% ; height:auto">
      <div id="insta3">
        <p>Hover 3</p>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" style="text-align:center; width:40%">
      <img id="iinsta4" src="url" style="width:100% ; height:auto">
      <div id="insta4">
        <p>Hover 4</p>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The `+` object can be used only with siblings that are next. Also, I have reduced your CSS. Please use `absolute` positions for positioning the `:hover`s. And, if you wanna maintain the HTML layout, you need to use JavaScript for this.

Answer (score 0):

```css
img ~ p {
  visibility: hidden;
}


img:hover ~ p {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="item">
        <h1>Hover 1</h1>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/100" />
        <p>Hover</p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="item">
        <h1>Hover 1</h1>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/100" />
        <p>Hover</p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="item">
        <h1>Hover 1</h1>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/100" />
        <p>Hover</p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="item">
        <h1>Hover 1</h1>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/100" />
        <p>Hover</p>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The example here seems complicated so I boiled it down to what I understood the question to be.  I hope this helps.  Feed back is welcome.